# Replace menu item with fontawesome icon without an extra module

Tags: 8, navigation, theming

I know there are several possibilities to use icons in menus with modules. Is there also a way to replace a menu item link with a fontawesome icon without installing a module? I only need to replace one menu link, so I don't want to use an extra module...

Comment: I solved it. I went to the fontawesome website, copied the icon (there is a function on every icon page), pasted it as menu item text and included the font file through CSS - quite easy.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this. When I paste <i class="fas fa-home"></i> in the Menu title, it prints just that. I have font aswsome module installed and fa icons show properly if I place it in a node. Just not on menu.

Comment: You have to copy the symbol itself, not the code

Comment: Did you include the font file in your theme?